# Pass an ID independent from model MVC/C#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I'd like to pass an id parameter from a controller to a view if possible completely independent from the model this particular view is using. Something like in the example below:

```
  public ActionResult Tickets(string id)
  {           

        return View("Ticket",id);
  }
```

And if this is possible, how can i call this id value from view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ViewBag`, `ViewData`, or `TempData` to pass the parameter independent from the View `Model`. To avoid using `dynamic`, use `ViewData` or `TempData`:

```
public ActionResult Tickets(string id)
{           
    ViewData["id"] = id;
    TempData["id"] = id;
    return View("Ticket");
}
```

And in the View, calls just as you defines it:

```
<i>ID:</i>@ViewData["id"]
<i>ID:</i>@TempData["id"]
```

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476967/What-is-ViewData-ViewBag-and-TempData-MVC-Option) is reference for differences between `ViewBag`, `ViewData`, and `TempData`:

Answer (score 2):

You can do like 
Using View bag

In Controller

```
public ActionResult Tickets(string id)
  {           
         ViewBag.id= id;
        return View("Ticket");
  }
```

In View

```
<b>ID:</b> @ViewBag.id<br />
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case it will work, and model will be this id string in View you can use it `@model System.String`.
Also you can pass by ViewBag. In Controller `ViewBag.Id=id;` in View `@ViewBag.Id`